# Questions on the Role of Kernel Threads in Process Interaction and User Thread I/O Handling

Tags: c, multithreading, operating-system, kernel, pthreads

I'm still a bit confused about how kernel threads are involved in the interaction of processes. Could someone help me clarify whether kernel threads are responsible for executing a process?

In the case that a user thread needs to perform an I/O operation, does the user thread need to request a kernel thread to carry out the writing?